# Lists Top Authors by Most Recent Posts

Tags: permalinks, loop, author, php, recent-posts

I'm trying to display a table format of the top authors listed by the most recent posts.  It should display the author, its avatar, the date, and the title of the post (with a link).

I have it listing the top authors along with the avatar. But it won't display the title of the post or the correct date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$uc=array();
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
$userpost = get_posts('showposts=1&author='.$bloguser->user_id);
$uc[$bloguser->user_id] = '';
if ($userpost) {
  $uc[$bloguser->user_id]=$userpost[0]->post_date;
}
}
arsort($uc);
$i = 0;
foreach ($uc as $key => $value) {

$user = get_userdata($key);
$post_id= $user->postID;
$post_title= $user->post_title;
$post_date= $user->post_date;
$post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);
if ($post_count && $i < 10) {
  $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);      
  ?>
  <table width="280" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                  <tr> 
                      <td width="15%"> <img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/images/authors/<?php print $user->user_login; ?>.jpg" onerror= "this.src='<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/images/authors/default.jpg'" width="45" height="50"></td>
                      <td width="85%" align="left">
                          <div class="sidebar_post"><?php printf ("<a href=\"index.php?p=%s\">%s</a></li>", $post_id,$post_title)?><br></div>
                          <div class="sidebar_author">By <?php print $user->display_name;?><br></div>
                          <div class="sidebar_postdate">Posted <?php the_time(get_option('date_format'));?></div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
 <?php    }
 $i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update: To get around this, I changed it up. It's probably not an ideal fix but it gave me what I needed.

```
            // Selects from tables wp_users and wp_posts, selecting published posts and ordering by its post_date, limited to 10
            $querystr = "SELECT * from wp_users, wp_posts WHERE wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 10";

              $news=$wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

              foreach($news as $np)
              {
                $authorID = $np->authorID;
                $author_nickname = $np->user_login;
                $author_displayName = $np->display_name;
                $author_niceName = $np->user_nicename;
                $post_id= $np->postID;
                $post_title= $np->post_title;
                $post_date= $np->post_date;
```

Comment: That's a) an unescaped and unsafe query open for injections and b) not portable as you don't use the proper prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `WP_User_Query` and then go through the results:

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 
    'role' => 'author', 
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta' 
) );
$editors = $wp_user_search->get_results();
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $editors );
echo '</pre>';
```